# How to create document with an index in ElasticSearch using NEST library in .NET?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use elastic search for the first time in C# and I am trying to create a document which is similar to a row in sql.

For what I understand, index is similar to a table and document is a row. I tried using CreateDocumentAsync method but it does not have any parameter to pass in the index so I am not sure how do I create a document with a particular index. I cannot use default index because our product can have many indices. First I am checking if the index exists and if it does not then it creates the index and then the document

Some code here

```
public async Task<CreateResponse> CreateDocumentAndIndex<T>(T document, string index) where T : class
{
    CreateResponse response = new(); 
    if (_client.Indices.Exists(index).Exists)
    {
        response = await _client.CreateDocumentAsync<T>(document);
    }
    else
    {
        await _client.IndexAsync(document, idx => idx.Index(index));
        response = await _client.CreateDocumentAsync<T>(document);
    }         
    return response;
}
```

Now to use this I have a function that calls this method

```
var response = await elasticSearchClient.CreateDocumentAndIndex<DbContextEventData>(eventData,"test");
```

But it gives me an error when it is trying to create a document. Is there a way to pass in index when creating a row/document in elastic search

Comment: It would greatly help if you could give us the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is tagged `elasticsearch-5`, so assuming you're using NEST 5.6.6, the index can be specified at the same time as creating a document

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var createResponse = await client.CreateAsync(new { foo = "bar" }, c => c
    .Index("my-index") // index
    .Type("_doc") // document type
    .Id("1") // document id
);
```

EDIT:

Since you're using Elasticsearch 6.3.0, you **must** use the latest NEST 6.x client, which at time of writing is [6.8.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/6.8.10). With NEST 6.8.10, a create document API call is as follows

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .PrettyJson()
        .DefaultTypeName("_doc") // doc types are gone in future versions, so best to index with this default doc type name
        .OnRequestCompleted(LogToConsole);
        
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    
    if (client.IndexExists("my-index").Exists) 
    {
        client.DeleteIndex("my-index");
    }

    var document = new MyDocument
    {
        Foo = "Bar",
        Baz = 1
    };

    var createResponse = client.Create(document, c => c
        .Index("my-index") // index
        .Id("1") // document id
    );
    
    var returnedDocument = client.Get<MyDocument>("1", g => g.Index("my-index"));
}

public class MyDocument
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}

private static void LogToConsole(IApiCallDetails callDetails) 
{
    if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var jObjects = new List<JObject>();
        using (var sr = new StringReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)))
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
            while (jsonTextReader.Read())
                jObjects.Add((JObject)JObject.ReadFrom(jsonTextReader));
        }

        var formatting = jObjects.Count == 1
            ? Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
            : Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
        var json = string.Join("\n", jObjects.Select(j => j.ToString(formatting)));
        Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n{json}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                 $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                 $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                 $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
    }
}
```

which logs the following to the console

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/my-index/_doc/1/_create?pretty=true
{
  "foo": "Bar",
  "baz": 1
}

Status: 201
{
  "_index" : "my-index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}

------------------------------

GET http://localhost:9200/my-index/_doc/1?pretty=true

Status: 200
{
  "_index" : "my-index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "foo" : "Bar",
    "baz" : 1
  }
}

------------------------------
```

Comment: What is document id here? I am creating a document so how can I get this id? I am creating a generic method for all the classes to be used so I do not know what will be the primary key of the document or object

Comment: I do not have the option of Type here and if I remove type, I get an error document mapping cannot start with _
I am using Elastic Search .NET 7.16

Comment: @LearnAspNet what version of NEST and what version of Elasticsearch are you using? The Create API requires an id to be provided for a document- if you need Elasticsearch to generate an id for documents as they are indexed, use the Index API (or Bulk API with index operations for batches of documents)

Comment: .NEST 7.16.0 and Elastic Search 6.3.0

Comment: Like I said it does not work. It says CreateDescriptor does not contain a definition of Type and no accessible extension method that accepts 'Type'. Also I do not have id of document.
I would like the document to be created under a particular index

Comment: You need to use the 6.x NEST client if you're targeting Elasticsearch 6.3.0- there can be and are breaking changes between Elasticsearch 6.x and 7.x, which also mean that there are breaking changes in the client. Therefore, you should use the major version of the client that matches the major version of Elasticsearch. I've added a full example with NEST 6.8.10 targeting Elasticsearch 6.3.0.